# Labels -1, 0 and 1 for classification in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, label, output, classification

I am trying to write a model that outputs a vector of length N consisting of labels -1,0 and 1. Each of the labels depicts one of three decisions for the system participants (wireless devices). So the vector depicts a system state that is then passed on to an optimization problem in the next step. Due to the fix problem formulation that is awaiting the output vector a selection of 0,1 and 2 instead is not possible.

After coming across this tanh function to supply the -1,0 and 1 values:
`1.5 * backend.tanh(alpha * x) + 0.5 * (backend.tanh(-(3 / alpha) * x))` from [here](https://r2rt.com/beyond-binary-ternary-and-one-hot-neurons.html), I was wondering how exactly this output layer and the penultimate layer can be built to suply this vector of labels {-1,0,1}. I tried using the above function in the output layer in a simple Iris classificator. But this resulted in terrible accuracy compared to the one achieved with 0,1,2 and softmax output layer.

Thanks in advance,
with kind regards,
Yuka

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like the outputs are actually "numerically related", for lack of a better term. Meaning, the labels could just as well be "left", "right", "up". So I think your best bet is to have 3 output nodes in the final layer, with softmax activation function, with each of the three nodes representing each of the three labels, using a Cross entropy loss function.

If your training data currently has the target as -1/0/1, you should one-hot encode it so that each target is a vector of length 3. So label 0 might be `[0,1,0]`

Comment: Thank youvery much for your input. I would like to also mention that the optimization result is then used to evaluate the output of the model in a scheme that is outside of the actual model training process. So I was not sure if simply using the one-hot encoding would cause any problem in this evaluation. I will give it a try with the one-hot encoding.

Comment: Could you show me how you are building your model?

Comment: Hey, sure. I wrote a simple example of my setup.

`from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np


K = 3
N = 5
M = 5

input = np.random.randint(10, 31, (1, K * N * M))


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape=(1, K * N * M)))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dense(K*N*M, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

print(model.predict(input))`